# Copying a fresh Drupal installation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm working on a wamp development environment. I've created a new database and used it to create a new drupal installation at `wamp/www/drupalsite`. This installation is unmodified and doesn't have any extra modules added to it.

What if I want to create an exact copy or this installation so I don't repeat the installation process. My guess is I'd have to create a new fresh database and copy the `/drupalsite/` folder to `/drupalsite2/`, but what other settings do I need to change to make this work perfectly as I had installed it from scratch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only other thing you need to change is the setting that points to the database. This can be found in `sites/default/settings.php`. Just do a search for `$db_url` and you'll find it.